# Safely drilling holes in a sill plate/top plate

Tags: structural

I’ve recently moved to an end unit 3story town house (plus basement) and had to pass ethernet cable through the floors, however from 1st floor to basement I had issues and made multiple holes to find the right direction (there are other couple more small holes not on the pictures). These were done on a sill plate/top plate.

Did I screw up everything and compromised my house’s structure? I am desperate!

[image]

Comment: Is there more to this (not just more holes, but more information) which you're not telling or showing us? What is it which makes you so concerned about what you've done?

Comment: Which is it—a sill plate, or a top plate?  The latter is unlikely to ever have anything nailed to it; the former could have baseboard nailed to it.  I suppose you could cut a piece of pipe to encase the cable.

Answer (score 4):

You are allowed to make holes about 1/3 of the widest dimension of a piece of structure.  They should be closer to the centre than near the edges.

Top/bottom plates have a bit more leeway, so you are okay.

If making holes in joists/studs you want to keep the holes close to the centre, near the edges does tend to weaken them.

If electric wire or plumbing pipes are closer than an inch and a half from the edge, you are suppose to use protection plates, so the next person does not nail/screw into the wires/pipes.  Low voltage(ethernet) not as important.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Was thinking only in 2D.

Answer (score 2):

You could have come and asked for advice *first*, but too late now.

Anyway, it appears that you have a hole so close to the edge as to be effectively a notch, but it's not a notch so large that it should be a problem (though it does leave your ethernet cable vulnerable to being hit by a screw.)

If doing this again, a small hole in the drywall is **just as much work (sometimes more) to patch as a big one**, so cut out a generous hole to work in (if you go halfway onto the stud on either side it makes the ultimate repair easier) and drill your cable holes in the center of the structural member, not at the edge.

You should consider (but are not required to for ethernet, as you are for power wiring) placing a protective steel plate over the section of plate with the hole in it to reduce the odds of the cable being hit by a screw. That will require removing some more drywall. That's not needed if you drill in the center, if excessively long screws are not used.

Answer (score 0):

The time to be desperate is before you drill the holes, not after. You'll be fine with this but the hole is too close to the edge and any cables could be pierced by future drywall screws, nails.